# How to call anonymous inner class in java

Tags: java, android

In the code, there is an alert box(for logout functionality). 
This alert box is created inside a method (i.e. logout method) and then two onClickListener are anonymously added to it. 
How can I call these anonymous listeners from outside?

Code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      //some logic
   }
}
```

What I need is to somehow call this onClick method and pass the instance of same dialog box.
I have read examples of doing this with reflection, but in those examples anonymous class was a subclass i.e. return value of 'new' was catched

Comment: what do you mean by calling it from outside?

Comment: You can create a reference variable as a global then when using in inner class initialize that with anonymous class using `this` keyword. Or you can create a separate method and use reference of that class as a parameter of that method.

Comment: You can't, it doesn't have a name. That's why it's called anonymous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the listener into a field variable.

```
private final DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogYesListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
      //some logic
   }
};

AlertDialog.Builder builder
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogYesListener);
```

Comment: if that's what you meant, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Refactor your code to have a reference to an instance of an `DialogInterfact.OnClickListener` like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
         //some logic
    }
}


builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", listener);
```

2) I don't know whether there is such an API, but if yes, you can try to extract listener implementation from a builder. **Pseudocode** should look like this:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener =
   builder.getPositiveButton().getListener(); //adjust this to a real API
```